# YARN ContainerIDs from Client

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to get the various container IDs and hostnames from the YARN client after the client has submitted the appContext ?  I suppose that would mean after the containers have been allocated can the information be communicated back to the client?

If this is not possible does the RM Web Interface provide this info ?

Answer (score 5):

YARN CLI has an option to get the list of containers from the Application Attempt ID. You can get the list of containers, by following the steps below.

- **Step 1: Get the list of Application Attempts from the Application ID**

  From the YARN application ID, you can get a list of application attempts, using the following command:

  ```
  yarn applicationattempt -list <Application ID>
  ```

  The description of this command reads:

  ```
  -list <Application ID>    List application attempts for application.
  ```

  For e.g.

  ```
  yarn applicationattempt -list application_1452267331813_0009
  ```
- **Step 2: Get the containers using Application Attempt ID**

  After you get list of application attempts, for each application attempt, you can get a list of containers, using following command:

  ```
  yarn container -list <Application Attempt ID>
  ```

  The description of this command reads:

  ```
  -list <Application Attempt ID>    List containers for application attempt.
  ```

  For e.g.:

  ```
  yarn container -list appattempt_1452267331813_0009_000001
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Wondering if there's also a way to get logs of the container once we get the containerId from cli?

Comment: After you get the Container ID from yarn container -list <Application Attempt ID>, You can get logs of the Container ID by running the following CLI:
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -containerId <Container ID>

Answer (score 0):

Rather ugly but can be done through a series URL requests to the ResourceManager, NodeManager, and various ContainerLog urls:

```
# Resource Manager Info for Given Application
curl http://RM:PORT/ws/v1/cluster/apps/<app_id>

amHostHttpAddress = data['app']['amHostHttpAddress']

# List containers with id, nodeId, containerLogsLink, etc
curl http://<amHostHttpAddress>/ws/v1/node/containers

# stdout/stderr for a specific container
curl http://<containerLogsLink>/stdout/?start=0"
curl http://<containerLogsLink>/stderr/?start=0"
```

This method works but there should probably be a cleaner way of doing this in YARN JAVA API